# proper way to import component vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm confused on the proper way to bring in components across the project for use in other files.

My vue js project structure is as follows:

```
.
├── node_modules
├── public
│   └── favicon.svg
|   └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── views
│       └── Main_screen.vue
|   └── App.vue
|   └── main.js
|   └── routes.js
├── vue.config.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
```

For example, in `vue.config.js`, I have the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    api_url: 'http://localhost'
 }
```

I am interested in using the `api_url` as a global variable so that no matter which file I am in, I can reference it. Within my `main.js` I imported as:

```
import api_url from '../vue.config.js'
Vue.prototype.api_url = api_url
```

I can use it within routes.js without a problem ( `import { api_url } from '../vue.config'` ) but within the Main_screen.vue, I get an import error using the same statement.

If you could reference a good resource to help me understand the structure I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: The vue.config.js file is not supposed to be used as a global variable storage, it's just the configuration for the vue-cli package.
To register global variable, you can use environment variables or a const in your `main.js` file (and then registrer is globally with the `Vue.prototype` as you did) :)

Answer (score 0):

`../` or just `..` is shorthand for the directory above the current one. so you are searching for `vue.config` in `src` folder if you used it in `Main_screen.vue` and searching for the file in the parent of `src` when you use it in `main.js`. try importing it like this in `Main_screen.vue`:

`import { api_url } from '../../vue.config'`

On the other hand one dot `.` means the current directory which means if you import something like `import { api_url } from './vue.config'` inside `main.js` it will give you an error because you are searching for the file inside `src` folder

**Edit**

As **Lawrence Cherone** said in the comments:

`import { api_url } from '../../../../../../vue.config'` can happen quickly in a larger project, is better to do `import { api_url } from '~/vue.config'`. `~` being where `package.json` is.

Comment: `import { api_url } from '../../../../../../vue.config'` can happen quicly in a larger project, is better to do `import { api_url } from '~/vue.config'`. `~` being where package.json is